Respobse code from Okhttp request 403 but using webview was 200
As title ,when I was using okhttp request webapi ,the question only happen on china ip location,the request response 403 but I try the same url in webview is 200!  I also see the webiew show redirect page
someone can give me a tip to resolve this issue by using okhtttp and return 200? 

Ask the developers of the Web site.

Which URL you were trying to access?
